# which spark dataframe plan query would work faster

Tags: scala, apache-spark

out of both query plan for the dataframe can anybody help me understand which would perform better.

1 dataframe:

```
    val df =  data.filter((col("regionId") < 0))    
    val dfn = data.filter(not(col("regionId") < 0))    
    val dff = df.union(dfn)    

    Optimized Plan:

    Union
    :- Project [regionId#3044L]    
    :  +- Filter (isnotnull(regionId#3044L) && (regionId#3044L < 0))    
    :     +- Relation[regionId#3044Ltimestamp#3046L] parquet    
    +- Project [regionId#3044L]    
       +- Filter (isnotnull(regionId#3044L) && (regionId#3044L >= 0))    
          +- Relation[regionId#3044Ltimestamp#3046L] parquet
```

2 dataframe:

```
    val df =  data.filter((col("regionId") < 0))    
    val dfn = data.except(df)    
    val dff = df.union(dfn)    

    Optimized Plan:

    Union
    :- Project [regionId#3044L]    
    :  +- Filter (isnotnull(regionId#3044L) && (regionId#3044L < 0))
    :     +- Relation[regionId#3044Ltimestamp#3046L] parquet
    +- Aggregate [regionId#3044L], [regionId#3044L]    
       +- Join LeftAnti, (regionId#3044L <=> regionId#3174L)    
          :- Project [regionId#3044L]      
          :  +- Relation[regionId#3044L,timestamp#3046L] parquet     
          +- Project [regionId#3174L]          
             +- Filter (isnotnull(regionId#3174L) && (regionId#3174L < 0))       
                +- Relation[regionId#3174L,timestamp#3176L] parquet
```

Answer (score 0):

The former one.

- In the first case you need only two narrow scans of the data.
- In the second case you need full scans, and additional shuffle.

So the two filters are clearly a winner.